# Creating an IL instruction with an inline argument using Mono.Cecil

Tags: .net, mono.cecil, mutation-testing

I'm playing with mutation testing at the moment. One of the mutations I'm looking at involves swapping parameters, for which I may need to swap, for example `Ldarg.0` and `Ldarg_S` with an operand indicating the index.

The operand type for this is an inline arg, which in Mono.Cecil I believe requires me to create a properly instantiated `ParameterDefinition` to store the 32-bit int index. Does anyone have enough experience with Cecil to point me in the right direction of an easy way to create an `Instruction` instance with `OpCode` of `Ldarg_S` and an `Operand` of the appropriate type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two kinds of opcodes here, `ldarg.0`, and `ldarg` (and its _s) variant.

The first one is a “macro” opcode, meaning that it's used to reduce the size of the code for typically used values.

If you need to modify the parameters of a method, I suggest you firs transform all macro opcodes to a complete form, this is done using the `SimplifyMacros()` extension method on `MethodBody` from the helper library Mono.Cecil.Rocks:

```
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono.Cecil.Cil;
using Mono.Cecil.Rocks;

// ..

method.Body.SimplifyMacros();
```

When this is done, an existing `ldarg.0` instruction will now be `ldarg` with the correct operand, which is as you guessed, a `ParameterDefinition`.

With that in place, you can re-order the parameters, and create new instructions:

```
var il = method.Body.GetILProcessor();
var instruction = il.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg, aParameterDefinition);
il.InsertBefore(xxx, instruction);
```

When you're done, you can call the inverse of `SimplifyMacros()`, `OptimizeMacros()`, which will try to, well, optimize the opcodes into their macro form if possible.

One thing you'll have to take care of, is that the first argument of a instance method, the implicit “this”, is represented with the `method.Body.ThisParameter` special parameter which you won't find in the .Parameters collection of the method.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even realise you hung out on SO Jb - thanks very much for the reply. I've already dealt with the "this" parameter for an instance method, that's fine. And I have a workaround at the moment, I just don't like the look of it. I'll give that a try and let you know how it goes - +1 for now, expect that'll become a big tick in the morning.

Comment: `SimplifyMacros` has made my project much easier. Very nice - thanks.